# What's the difference between 「〜とつきあう」 and 「〜につきあう」?

Tags: word-choice, particles

I understand that つきあう means "to hang out with, to date, to keep company…". I've seen it used both with と and with に, but I haven't been able to figure out when to use which. So for example, what's the difference in meaning between

```
彼とつきあう and
彼につきあう？
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an important difference in nuance and often even in meaning.

Nuance:

(Someone) **と**つきあう = "to hang out with someone willingly"

(Someone) **に**つきあう = "to hang out with someone **unwillingly**" because you feel obliged to do so.

Depending on context, 「(Someone) **と**つきあう」 means "to date someone" and when it means this, the phrase cannot be replaced with「(Someone) **に**つきあう」.  That is unless you are dating that person unwillingly.